# Google Analytics (gtag) cross-domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've an website with two domains, everything is redirected using JQuery (no a href="xxx"), how can i pass the _ga parameter on URL manually? I just want to get the client ID and pass with jquery like:

```
  window.location
  .replace('https://mynewdomain.com/?_ga=' + CLIENTID);
  return;
```

on mynewdomain.com i have:

```
      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', {'linker': {'domains': ['olddomain.com','mynewdomain.com'], 'accept_incoming': true}});
```

I'm really going crazy with this...

Comment: So, you are using ajax in jquery? For requesting some data from mynewdomain.com?

Comment: Not really, i just redirect the user for a new domain after i check some information on a php script. I just want to know how to set: https://mynewdomain/index.php?_ga=1.2.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX to work, where _ga= is the cookie _ga from olddomain (i got it checking my cookies) but it just ignore the parameter.